FlowiseAI results of api different from playground on Flowiseai Llamaindex
I am using flowiseai to create RAG app, i have built chatbot on flowiseai , tested it and it works with great accuracy, now i connected it with my flask app as an api, but the results now i am getting is not upto the mark i don't know why the issue is being caused , i just used their api and send questions from my flask app.
API_URL = "https://flowise.xyz/api"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer K3VXa9hTkA2jwTMN4RASTYQFxN/H60D0ar"}
question = request.json.get('question')
response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json={"question":question})
answer=response.json()

Any idea what can be the issue?
